# Creating a local nuget package for web forms project

Tags: nuget

We already use nuget for a few things such as the facebook api, However we also use some bespoke dlls which don't seem to be avaible through nuget. So is it possible for us to create a nuget package containing these bespoke dlls as well as links to ones that are already availible via nuget.org.

At the moment we manually add them ppl save them in the bin folder which gets deleted when you clear the solution if you're getting build issues. Or they save it in some directory so when you get latest vs freaks out because they're not there. then we fix them and check in  the csproj others will get build issues

Answer (score 0):

1. Host a local nuget server http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages
2. Create your nuget package,http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds
3. Upload it in your local server that you have hosted
4. Update your VS config to point to your local nuget server